# Input text at Select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched a lot, but did not find how to do a multiple select box, and next to each option to add a text box, something like this:

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option><input id="volvo"/> 
  <option value="saab">Saab</option><input id="saab"/>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option><input id="opel"/>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option><input id="audi"/>
</select>
```

I would appreciate any help very

Comment: You can't, selects can only have options as children, so the input has to go inside the option.

Comment: My question other than asking there.
There have solutions add one text box, I want to add a text box for each option, always be visible and active.

Comment: On the other hand, options can't contain elements either, only text, so this can't be done, unless you create your own custom select